# Positive integer solutions to $a^2b^2-(a-b)^2=s^2t^2-(s+t)^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am trying to find all positive integer solutions $(a,b,s,t)$ to $a^2b^2-(a-b)^2=s^2t^2-(s+t)^2$.

If $ab=st$ and $a-b=s+t$, then the solution corresponds to a Pythagorean Triple $(m,n,p)$ in the following way:
\begin{equation*}
a=\frac{m+n+p}{2},\quad b=\frac{m+n-p}{2};\quad s=\frac{-m+n+p}{2},\quad t=\frac{m-n+p}{2}
\end{equation*}
However, I just ran matlab and found other solutions. For example, $(18,6,28,4)$ and $(26,6,90,2)$. Here are more:

$(102,2,18,10)$

$(108,2,32,6)$

$(20,10,116,2)$

$(36,6,12,18)$ (P-triple related)

$(40,6,24,10)$ (P-triple related)

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: There is a second family of solutions based on any number that can be expressed as $2x^2+16$ and is the sum of two squares. This leads to the example $(108,12,130,10)$. To find it, add $4$ to your equation and rewrite both sides as differences of squares again. Your first extra solution belongs to this family.

Comment: Thanks! Got it: $(ab+2)^2-(a+b)^2=(st-2)^2-(s-t)^2$. The other solution does not satisfy either $ab=st$ or $ab=st-4$. I'm working on it.

Comment: Just a remark. If you fix $a,s$ then the resulting equation is quadratic in $b,t$. This means, for example, that it's easy to parameterize all rational solutions. You just start from a special family of solutions $sol(a,s)$ and you find all the other by solving linear equations (trace a line with rational slope and find the second intersection). 

Easy families of special rational solutions are: (a,s,s,-a)  (a,a/(a+1),s,s/(s-1)) or your Pythagorean one.

I tried with the first, but the result has an ugly denominator, so it's difficult to see the integer solutions. You may try the others.

Comment: Thanks Luca, it's not easy though.